# Ubuntu server on RPI 4 boot hangs on cloud init

Tags: boot, boot-issues, ubuntu

I've installed the image `ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` on an sd card and am trying to boot ubuntu server for the first time on my raspberry pi 4.

I get to this stage in the boot and it hangs:

```
ubuntu 19.10 ubuntu tty1

ubuntu login: [...] cloud-init[....] Cloud-init v. 19.2-36-g059d049c-Oubuntu3 running 'modules:config' at ...
[...] cloud-init[....] Cloud-init v. 19.2-36-g059d049c-Oubuntu3 running 'modules:final' at ...
[...] cloud-init[....] Cloud-init v. 19.2-36-g059d049c-Oubuntu3 finished at ...  Datasource DatasourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/mmcblkp01][dsmode=net]
```

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185560/ubuntu-19-10-on-raspberrypi-4-hangs-on-first-boot) and tried creating the file /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt with total_mem=3072 (the file does not already exist), but it has no effect.

How should I proceed?

EDIT:

After updating /usercfg.txt on the vfat partition I advance to the previous logs, plus:

```
[  ok  ] Started execute cloud user/final scripts.
[  ok  ] Reached target Cloud-init target.
```

and I'm hanging once again.

Note there's some noise about ssh keys that I don't remember seeing before, I can give more info on that if necessary.

Comment: "*Set `total_mem=3072` in `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`. 
(If you mount the sd card in another computer, the usercfg.txt is on the small vfat partition.)*" https://askubuntu.com/a/1182566/859552

Comment: @M.Rostami Thanks for pointing that out, appreciate it. I've advanced slightly further but still remain blocked.  The question is updated if you've ever encountered this before.  Thanks again.

Comment: It seems around the "ACPI Shutdown". Therefore, change the power supply and test it again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the exact same issue on a P3 - tried different ISOs but no joy

I was able to fix by disabling cloud init via ssh.

1) get the IP address of the Pi - I was at home so just logged onto my router and got it from there

2) in windows command line on another machine login using command :

```
ssh ubuntu@[ip address]
```

the default password is '*ubuntu*'

3) you will be forced to change the password, do this

4) you will then be logged out - log back in using the above and the new password

5) when you get to the UNIX bash prompt run the command

```
touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

6) exit and restart your Pi

hope this helps

Comment: thanks you just saved me a whole lot of trouble :)

Comment: Thanks. This really helped. I had the exact same problem as the OP and this was the exact answer I needed.

Comment: Weird, I can't even get as far as ssh onto mine. They seem to hang before that is available.